# AttributeError with Requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am getting the error :  AttributeError : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
with the following code, and am unable to work out why:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/healthandsocialcare/causesofdeath/datasets/deathregistrationsandoccurrencesbylocalauthorityandhealthboard/2021"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")

latest_file = soup.find('div', {'class': 'margin-top-md--4 margin-bottom-sm--4 margin-bottom-md--5'})
a_class_section = latest_file.find('a', {'class': 'btn btn--primary btn--thin btn--narrow btn--small'})

print(a_class_section)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the full traceback, so that it is clear on which line the error is raised. I have run the code and I don't get an error.

Comment: your code works for me. I get `<a class="btn btn--primary btn--thin btn--narrow btn--small" data-gtm-date="Latest" data-gtm-download-file="lahbtables2021week10.xlsx" data-gtm-download-type="xlsx" data-gtm-type="download-version-xlsx" href="/file?uri=/peoplepopulationandcommunity/healthandsocialcare/causesofdeath/datasets/deathregistrationsandoccurrencesbylocalauthorityandhealthboard/2021/lahbtables2021week10.xlsx" title="Download as xlsx">
xlsx
(3.6 MB)
</a>`

Comment: Based on the code you've posted, it would seem that `latest_file` is `None` on your machine, @Sanch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code didn't work with an older version of BeautifulSoup4, however it works with version 4.9

Comment: Could you share how you downloaded the file using this code?